# Cassandra JMX java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199

Tags: java, cassandra, jmx

Our Cassandra 2.2 cluster (on CentOS 7) is working fine except one thing. As soon as I put `LOCAL_JMX=no` in **cassandra-env.sh**, Cassandra fails to start with the following error:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

The relevant configuration is as follows:

```
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/pki/cassandra/keys/.keystore"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password1"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/cassandra/certs/.truststore"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password2"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true"
```

I indeed verified if there isn't anything running on the port and it isn't. If I change the port, the same result.
What helped was to use different ports for `jmxremote.port` and for `jmxremote.rmi.port`, although it is against recommendations in manuals. Unfortunately even that I wasn't able to use **nodetool** getting `NoSuchObjectException: 'no such object in table'` exception.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Where is `cassandra-env.sh` I have the same error without having written `LOCAL_JMX=no` in this file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was in the following line:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

When I switched it to true, it was possible to start Cassandra with the settings mentioned above (using a common port).

However it didn't mean the problems were over, because while using **nodetool** I started to get: `nodetool: Failed to connect to - ConnectIOException: 'non-JRMP server at remote endpoint'`

The final solution is that the problem is in SSL. The protocol does not support it for JMX. Hence the only solution is to switch it off and the working configuration is as follows:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/pki/cassandra/keys/.keystore"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password1"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/cassandra/certs/.truststore"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password2"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=false"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=false"
```

Then everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I also enabled

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true"
```

Yet, when I ran nodetool with the --ssl option I was able to authenticate without any issues. So perhaps you missed the --ssl option?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandara also has a conflict with VMware. After stopping the VMware services, Cassandra started correctly.